# Rigid type error

Tags: haskell

I have the following code:

```
data Argument  = Argument  { ttype :: Type, value :: String }
data Predicate = Predicate { lemma     :: String
                           , arguments :: [Argument] }

class Throw a where
    throw :: a -> a -> Predicate

instance Throw Argument where
    throw x y = Predicate { lemma = "throw", arguments = [x, y] }

qWho :: (Argument -> b -> Predicate) -> b -> [Argument]
qWho rel arg@(Argument x y) = STUFF HAPPENS HERE
qWho OTHER PATTERNS HAPPEN HERE
```

The idea is that `b` in the `qWho` signature can either be an `Argument` or a `Predicate` (in the case of the first pattern, an `Argument`), and will act accordingly. The problem is, when I try to compile it, I get the following error:

```
context.hs:162:11: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘b’ with actual type ‘Argument’
      ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          qWho :: forall b. (Argument -> b -> Predicate) -> b -> [Argument]
        at context.hs:161:1-55
    • In the pattern: Argument x y
      In an equation for ‘qWho’:
          qWho rel (Argument x y)
            = STUFF I'M LEAVING OUT FOR BREVITY'S SAKE
    • Relevant bindings include
        rel :: Argument -> b -> Predicate (bound at context.hs:162:6)
        qWho :: (Argument -> b -> Predicate) -> b -> [Argument]
          (bound at context.hs:162:1)
```

Any ideas why I'm getting this error? Also, FYI, I'm brand new to Haskell, and this is part of an assignment, so while I'm not looking to have the assignment done for me, I'm just looking for the reason behind the error. Finally, all the above code (except `qWho`) was provided as part of the assignment, so the solution probably shouldn't be that I have to change that part! :D

Thanks!

Comment: I suspect you misunderstand the meaning of the type `(Argument -> b -> Predicate) -> b -> [Argument]`. As written, the caller of `qWho`, not the implementer, gets to choose `b`. If I decide I want to call `qWho` and hand it a `Argument -> Int -> Predicate` function and an `Int`, or decide I want to call `qWho` and hand it a `Argument -> (forall f. Contrapunctor f => f Whoziwhatsit -> Prepromorphism) -> Predicate` and a `forall f. Contrapunctor f => f Whoziwhatsit -> Prepromorphism`, well, you as the implementor of `qWho` just have to Deal With It.

Comment: Are you _sure_ `qWho` is correct? As it stand, just `qWho :: (Argument -> b -> Predicate) -> b -> [Argument]` and `qWho rel arg@(Argument x y) = ...` are already at odds with each other. If you have a `b` without a constraint on it, it can not only be an `Argument` or a `Predicate` - it can be anything! Furthermore, the first line of the pattern match is saying that the `b` _has_ to be an `Argument` (which is also what the error message is telling you).

Comment: I was planning on matching more patterns. Having a `qWho rel pred@(Predicate x y) = ...` for `b` as a `Predicate` and a `qWho _ _ = ...` to handle incorrect patterns. Would that not solve the problem?

Comment: Oh, wait, so I think I realize the issue now. I was doing something like declaring a function `foo :: b -> Bool`, then writing a bunch of patterns that match specific things that `b` can be, like `foo 1 = ...; foo 'a' = ...;foo etc.`. Which is illegal. Is that it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it thanks to @DanielWagner and @Alec

Instead of trying to match patterns, I declared two instances (not sure that's the right way to say it) of the type class `Who`:

```
class Who b where
    qWho :: (Argument -> b -> Predicate) -> b -> [Argument]

instance Who Argument where
    qWho rel arg = ...

instance Who Predicate where
    qWho rel p = ...
```

Comment: This makes much more sense. Good job!